# How to calculate significance for an A/B test for average revenue per daily active user over a 1-week test period?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, ab-test

One simple approach is to use "per active day" metrics. e.g. "revenue_per_active_day" . However there is a fundamental flaw with this approach. e.g. during a 7-day period, let's say user 1 is active on 1 day and generates 1 dollar of revenue. and let's say user 2 is active on 7 days and generates 7 dollars of revenue. These two users would both have "revenue_per_active_day" of 1 dollar and thus have exactly the same impact on the A/B test analysis result, whereas in reality the more active user would have more impact on ARPDAU (average revenue per daily active user), so basically we're biased against heavy users / biased towards light users.

A potentially better approach (not sure) is to treat each day of the test period as a separate A/B test and use the "repeated measure ANOVA" statistical test to determine whether or not the test group mean is different from the control group mean in a statistically significant way. Repeated measures design - Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design) Repeated Measures ANOVA (https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/repeated-measures-anova-statistical-guide.php)
However this is inherently complicated. The vanilla case of Repeated Measure ANOVA (rANOVA) assumes "sphericity" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUXdWUHJRqA
) but almost always the assumption of sphericity is violated. There is a way to adjust for this but it's not perfect (https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/sphericity-statistical-guide-2.php)

Comment: 0. Welcome to the CV community. 1. Can you please define what `ARPDAU` stands for exactly? 2. Given that you recognise a short-coming of the metric used, is there a particular reason why would you stick with this metric? An *excellent* rule-of-thumb when designing metrics is that they have a single moving part, e.g. if there are a ratio, only the denominator or the numerator is affected from the treatment, not both because it will be unclear what actually changed. The metric you propose is fine but maybe you just need to test for days active too?

Comment: Thanks! ARPDAU (average revenue per daily active user) was mentioned in the question title but I spelled it out again.  I have to use ARPDAU because it is already a commonly used official metric that everyone uses and tracks. But I understand what you mean re having a single moving part (ARPDAU has 2 moving parts, i.e. the numerator and denominator are both affected by the treatment, so maybe it's simply not a good metric to use for summarizing an experiment across multiple days).

Comment: I appreciate your point about "everyone uses it"; as you said, it depends what you want. Anecdote: We had a similar metric in my work that went in the gutter every-time our marketing team did a new big campaign. New users showed up, the denominator was getting inflated faster than the numerator and as new users are not high-spenders immediately "ARPDAU" suffered. One department's trash is another department's treasure...